# Typescript Compare two different enums and return the key if same value

Tags: typescript

i have 2 different enums, and given 1 enum i want to check if the value exists in the other enum and return the key.

```
function foo(enum2Value: enum2) {
    const enum1Key = Object.keys(enum1).find((key: any) => {
        return enum1[key] === enum2;
    });
    return enum1Key;
}
```

this code works. but i have to cast key to any. if i use string, then
 enum1[key] === enum2 does not work. What would be a better way of comparing two differnet enums

Comment: You're going against the language, potentially misusing enums. You don't typically rely on the underlying values of enums. that's why enum members with the same value are not considered the same... Just so you know, you probably should just be dealing with maps

Comment: Consider making this code into a [mcve] where the only issue present is the one you want help with; right now, `enum1` and `enum2` are not defined.

Answer (score 1):

```
const enumValByKey = (k: string, o: object) =>
    (k in o) ? (o as Record<typeof k, string | number>)[k] : null;

enumValByKey('ABC', enum1); // value of enum1.ABC, or null
```

My solution still requires an assertion unfortunately. `string | number` covers all that TS enums can be to my knowledge.

Curious if there's a way to model this without an assertion.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why exactly you want to do this, but it is possible to do it without `any`.

```js
function foo(enum2Value: enum2) {
    const enum1Key = (Object.keys(enum1) as (keyof typeof enum1)[]).find(key => {
        return enum1[key] === enum2Value as string;
    });
    return enum1Key;
}
```

First we cast the result of `Object.keys(enum1)` to `(keyof typeof enum1)[]`. This now means all possible values of `key` are valid keys of the enum `enum1`. Next we have to cast `enum2Value` to `string` as well because even though it's value is a string, TypeScript sees it as enum.

> BTW I'm assuming the `enum2` on the third line of your code is a typo and should actually be `enum2Value`.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/KYOwrgtgBKkIxQN4CgpQIYILxQEQDMB7Q3AGlQwCYodcAjdAJ12QF9llZovqU07seBgC8yFOtVpESbDvjAgAxgBcAloRBRpACh4A1dABswwAFwxwESgEokFNIo0BnZRfgBpYAE8aUbQHk6ACtgFQA6AGtvJ11LOFt0Jz8or0J8KGUvAAdgNLcIeIBtAF1rMPxVEAATbRSaAD47NGbmxmBlMEZNLjhClOKaLBx9IxMMJJdGSoBzAG57KFZreZa2jq78uE8vedYgA)